# Why is the second generic type of the TypeScript function not inferred correctly?

Tags: typescript, generics

why the return type of exampleOne is "hello world" and exampleTwo is string? How can i fix this?

```js
type SomeType = 'Hello' | 'Greeting'

function example<
  argument_1 extends SomeType,
  argument_2 extends string = string
>(
  arg: argument_2
): argument_2 {
  return arg
}

const exampleOne = example('hello world') // ReturnType: "hello world"
const exampleTwo = example<'Hello'>('hello world') // ReturnType: string
```

Comment: because you can;t partial infer thats why

Comment: Remove `argument_1` because is declared but its value is never read. I believe that is what you are looking for.